# Problems with PHP and MYSQL in designing this game

Tags: php, forms

***I am very very new to PHP and learning as I can, we have only studied the language for two weeks. please be patient with me. This is a file running on Xampp on localhost.****

I am designing a quiz game where the user has a dropdown box to select the grade level and then another dropdown box to select the category they want to choose from, then they click submit. I have a database set up with 3 tables (the grade level, the category, and a questions table with a list of 100 questions). If grade = 1 and category = 1 it will return the 5 questions that are 1st grade language questions.

My problem is that I want to be able to do all of this processing on the same page, but I am unsure if this is possible. My code is also really long because we have not been learning PHP for very long. The page will return the questions just fine, but I am having trouble getting it to verify the user's input for the 5 answer boxes that correspond to the correct answers pulled from the database. The output for the correct/incorrect loop is also displaying before the user can type in their answers and hit submit. I also have a score tally to keep up with wins or losses. Is it possible to do all of this on a single PHP page? 
I have two forms going, one for the stuff with the questions, the other for the stuff involving the answers.

I can paste some of my code in sections, but not all since it is really long. Again, I am pretty good at C++, but have not learned a lot about PHP.

```html
<!-- Previous form above for the questions that also has a form action of #. -->
<form action ="#" method = "post">
Your Answers:<br>
1) <input type="text" name="input1"><br><br>
2) <input type="text" name="input2"><br><br>
3) <input type="text" name="input3"><br><br>
4) <input type="text" name="input4"><br><br>
5) <input type="text" name="input5"><br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Check" id="check_answ"><br>
Correct Answers:<br>

<?php
   //check the answer box 
   $input1 = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'input1', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
   $input2 = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'input2', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
   $input3 = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'input3', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
   $input4 = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'input4', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
   $input5 = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'input5', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

    //function to store the answer query
   function storeQueryAns($category, $grade, $quesID)
   {
    $query_answer = "select answer from questions where catID = '$category' and gradeID = '$grade' and quesID = '$quesID'";
    return $query_answer;
   }
   $query_answer1 = storeQueryAns($category, $grade, $quesID1);
   $answer1 = mysqli_query($con, $query_answer1);
   
   $query_answer2 = storeQueryAns($category, $grade, $quesID2);
   $answer2 = mysqli_query($con, $query_answer2);
   
   $query_answer3 = storeQueryAns($category, $grade, $quesID3);
   $answer3 = mysqli_query($con, $query_answer3);
   
   $query_answer4 = storeQueryAns($category, $grade, $quesID4);
   $answer4 = mysqli_query($con, $query_answer4);
   
   $query_answer5 = storeQueryAns($category, $grade, $quesID5);
   $answer5 = mysqli_query($con, $query_answer5);
   
   //function to store the correct answers in a string variable
   function storeAnswer($answerID)
   {
    while($row = $answerID->fetch_assoc()) 
  {
        return (string)$row['answer']."<br>";
     }
   }
  
    //storing the correct answers in the variables 
   $CorrAnswer1 = storeAnswer($answer1);
   $CorrAnswer2 = storeAnswer($answer2);
   $CorrAnswer3 = storeAnswer($answer3);
   $CorrAnswer4 = storeAnswer($answer4);
   $CorrAnswer5 = storeAnswer($answer5);?>
   
      <!-- Printing out the correct answers -->
      <p>1) <?php echo $CorrAnswer1;?> </p>
 
   <p>2) <?php echo $CorrAnswer2;?> </p>
   
   <p>3) <?php echo $CorrAnswer3;?></p>
   
   <p>4) <?php echo $CorrAnswer4;?></p>
   
   <p>5) <?php echo $CorrAnswer5;?></p>

   
   <?php
   //function to check the answers 
   function checkAnswers($input, $CorrAnswer, &$total_win, &$total_loss)
   {
   if($input == $CorrAnswer)
   {
    echo nl2br("Correct!\n");
    $total_win++;
   }
   
   else if($input == NULL)
   {
    echo "Answer cannot be left blank.";
   }
   
   else 
   {
    echo nl2br("Incorrect!\n");
    $total_loss++;
   }
   }
   
   checkAnswers($input1, $CorrAnswer1, $total_win, $total_loss);
   checkAnswers($input2, $CorrAnswer2, $total_win, $total_loss);
   checkAnswers($input3, $CorrAnswer3, $total_win, $total_loss);
   checkAnswers($input4, $CorrAnswer4, $total_win, $total_loss);
   checkAnswers($input5, $CorrAnswer5, $total_win, $total_loss);
   
   ?>
   
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood correctly, first you want to collect the inputs and then show the correct answers.
a possible code could be this one

```
<?php
   $numInputs = 5;
   $i =1;
   $inputs= array();
   $valid=true;
   while($i <= $numInputs && $valid == true){
      $str = "input".$i;
      if(isset($_POST[$str]) && !preg_match("/^\s+$/", $_POST[$str])) $inputs[] = $_POST[$str];
      else $valid = false;
      $i++;
   }
   if($valid === true && sizeof($inputs) > 0){
      $answer1 = getQueryAns($category, $grade, $quesID1);
      checkAnswers($inputs[0], $answer1, $total_win, $total_loss);
      $answer2 = getQueryAns($category, $grade, $quesID2);
      checkAnswers($inputs[1], $answer2, $total_win, $total_loss);
      $answer3 = getQueryAns($category, $grade, $quesID3);
      checkAnswers($inputs[2], $answer3, $total_win, $total_loss);
      $answer4 = getQueryAns($category, $grade, $quesID4);
      checkAnswers($inputs[3], $answer4, $total_win, $total_loss);
      $answer5 = getQueryAns($category, $grade, $quesID5);
      checkAnswers($inputs[4], $answer5, $total_win, $total_loss); ?>
      Correct Answers:<br>
      <p>1) <?=$answer1;?> </p>
      <p>2) <?=$answer2;?> </p>
      <p>3) <?=$answer3;?></p>
      <p>4) <?=$answer4;?></p>
      <p>5) <?=$answer5;?></p>
   <?php }else{ ?>
         <form method = "post">
            Your Answers:<br>
            1) <input type="text" name="input1"><br><br>
            2) <input type="text" name="input2"><br><br>
            3) <input type="text" name="input3"><br><br>
            4) <input type="text" name="input4"><br><br>
            5) <input type="text" name="input5"><br><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Check" id="check_answ"><br>
         </form>       
   <?php  } 

    function checkAnswers($input, $CorrAnswer, &$total_win, &$total_loss){
     if($input == $CorrAnswer){
        echo nl2br("Correct!\n");
        $total_win++;
     }
     else{
        echo nl2br("Incorrect!\n");
        $total_loss++;
     }
   }
   function getQueryAns($category, $grade, $quesID){
      return $con->query("select answer from questions where catID = '$category' and gradeID = '$grade' and quesID = '$quesID'")->fetch_assoc()["answer"];
    }
?>
```

this will show the answers if none of the inputs are empty.
if not it shows the form.
Also if you collect all the quests in an array you can do a for to make the code shorter

Comment: Yes I want to have someone choose both dropdown options, hit submit, then that returns on the same page the 5 questions. Then there are 5 answer boxes and they type in their answers, then click submit and it returns again to the same page showing the correct answers and their score.

Comment: I used what you had given me and I had to pass the $con into the function, it kept giving errors. Anyways, it now doesn't show the answers after the user hits submit, even when all the answers are filled in. Also, I am still getting an error with it checking the input against the correct answer. I have tried many other things to get it to work.

Comment: Yes i forgot  to add $con into getQueryAns, what errors it gives you?

Comment: It was giving errors before I did the connect variable. It still doesn't check the input against the correct answer sql query. I have to figure that part out.